# .to_csv cambia el archivo original - Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la columna "confirmed_tweet_ids" se puede ver que cada celda está compuesta por una lista de numeros.
El problema viene al guardar el archivo y volver a cargarlo:

```
data.to_csv("data.csv",index=False)            #Guardo el archivo
pd.read_csv("D:data.csv")                  #Lo vuelvo a cargar desde la ruta donde lo guardé
```

Pero al cargar el archivo la columna ha cambiado y ahora aparece de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en las casillas de la columna donde antes había una lista con sus elementos, ahora consta cada elemento entre '  ' y ya no se considera una lista (ni me permite trabajar con las características de una lista):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien puede explicarme por que pasa esto y como puedo devolverle la característica de lista al elemento?

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el csv no es más que cadenas delimitadas por un separador. Al crear el csv la lista se convierte en cadena llamando a su método `__str__` y eso es lo que se agrega a la columna.

> ```
> >>> l = ["123", "456"]
> >>> str(l)
> "['123', '456']"
> ```

Al leer el archivo el parser no sabe que esa cadena representa una lista Python por lo que deja la columna como una cadena (`str`, tipo `object` en Pandas). La forma más simple de solucionar el problema es usar el argumento `converters` e indicarle que a esa columna le aplique una función que parsee la cadena a una lista y la retorne.

Podrías definir tu mismo la función para tu caso concreto (lista de cadenas) pero [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) ya permite esto de forma totalmente segura y fiable en este caso (a no ser que tus listas fueran muy muy largas, en cuyo caso podría generarse un desbordamiento de pila y bloquear el intérprete):

```
import ast
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": (54056853,),
                     "gender": ("M",),
                     "mbti": ("ENTJ",),
                     "confirmed_tweet_id": (["676", "452"],),
                     })

data.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", converters={"confirmed_tweet_id": ast.literal_eval})
```

> ```
> >>> data.loc[0, "confirmed_tweet_id"][0]
> '676'
> ```

Otra opción sería usar otro formato de archivo como parquet o el mismo JSON:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": (54056853,),
                     "gender": ("M",),
                     "mbti": ("ENTJ",),
                     "confirmed_tweet_id": ([676, 452],),
                     })

data.to_json("data.json", index=False, orient="split")
data = pd.read_json("data.json", orient="split")
```

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2121 fields in line 4, saw 2431

Comment: Corregido, simplemente faltaba importar el módulo de la biblioteca estándar `ast`.

Comment: si ya me di cuenta, importe ast pero me cargaba el dataframe con el mismo error, aunque con json me ha funcionado perfectamente, ¿alguna idea de porque? Gracias, te doy la respuesta.

Comment: Es extraño, acabo de probar mi ejemplo por las dudas y funciona como se espera, he añadido la salida. ¿Te sigue saliendo '[' en tu caso o tienes otro error?

Comment: Me sigue saliendo con el  '[' . Cabe añadir que el data es bastante grande, cada casilla tiene una lista de unos 3mil elementos y la columna posee 10mil casillas. ¿Puede ser por eso?